# Display data which was modified in SQL query

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework

I have an table 'users'. Users can modify their data eg. name, surname, email. and I want to send email to admin which will contain details about modified data. If user change only name and email i want to grab only changed data - in this case only name and email.

My form:

```
<form action="" method="post">
<input type="text" name="name">
<input type="text" name="surname">
<input type="text" name="email">
<input type="submit" value="Send">
</form>
```

It is possible that I can grab data which was modified in sql query, excluding data which are the same in table and in the form?
I have an idea that I must check each POST field that is the same as in database, but I have many more fields and this solution is not so good:

```
if($row['email'] !== $_POST['email']) { $changed_email = $_POST['email']; } 

if($row['name'] !== $_POST['name']) { $changed_name = $_POST['name']; }
```

There is any other solution that I can grab only modified data?
I'm using Zend Framework and all table fields are called same as POST data.

Comment: Is the form populated by the database or are they blank to allow the user to enter information? If it is populated, you can store the information in an array and do a foreach comparison of the $_POST to the database information. If the form is left blank for the user to fill in changed information, just check if the $_POST is left blank or there is a change provided. Unfortunately, without more information, an answer is very difficult to provide.

Comment: Form is populated by data from database. I storage all data sent by user in array and i can storage oryginal data in other array, but how make a foreach from that? I have to do double foreach with data from database and foreach with data from user? How to compare this two arrays? All fields are always send by form so I have to recognize which of these POST data are diffrent from data from database.

Answer (score 0):

You could loop through your `$_POST` array and use the key to fetch the corresponding value from the DB:

```
foreach($_POST as $key => $value){
    if($value !== $row[$key]){
        $changed[$key] = $value;
    }
}
```

However you may want to exclude some fields in the loop (for example the submit button):

```
$excluded_keys = array('submit', 'some_other_key');
foreach($_POST as $key => $value){
    if(in_array($key, $excluded_keys)) continue;

    if($value !== $row[$key]){
        $changed[$key] = $value;
    }
}
```